# What does 100x mean, for an SD card?

Tags: sd-card

When I read the information about an SD card, I notice there is an information that is reported as 100x. What does that mean? To what is it referring?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The x rating on an SD card is a measurement of read/write speed. 1x means a speed of 1.2 Mb/s, so 100x would mean a maximum speed of 120 Mb/s (or 15 MB/s). Whether or not this refers to maximum write speed or maximum read speed is vendor-specific.

Comment: I guess they will report the read access speed, to make think the SD card is more performant than it is. `:-)` Thank you for your reply.

Comment: It should also be noted that the speed is pretty much always given as a maximum (as in *up to*) as opposed to average speed.

Comment: To be precise, the convention is that the speed is given in the same format as for CD drives, so 1x is as gP says 1.2 Mb/s or the perhaps more known number 150 kB/s.