# How does 200x or 300x in relation to an SD card differ from the class rating?

Tags: sd-card, sdhc

I've always understood "class 10" (or whatever) to refer to the speed of an SD (or SDHC) card, but [apparently ratings like 200x or 300x also refer to speed](https://superuser.com/q/179278/23135).  How do the two rating systems differ?  Which is more standard and more reliable?  Is something like 300x simply used because there's no such thing as a class above 10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The speed class rating is the SD Association standard.  These numbers are the ones you see that range from 1 to 10 and will be inside a U or a C.  They represent the card's minimum performance.  The "x" rating is a commercial rating.  Manufacturers will give this number and it is the maximum potential of the card.

Lexar has a (PDF) white paper on the whole thing
titled [Understanding SD Association Speed Ratings](https://web.archive.org/web/20160402043444/http://www.lexar.com/files/product/datasheet/White_Paper_SD_Class_xRating_updatedUHS_Final_1.pdf). 
Additional  information is available at [Making Sense of Memory Cards](https://www.photo.net/learn/making-sense-of-memory-cards/).